# Testing solution to K&R C exercise 1-18 doesn't work

Tags: c

Below is the solution to exercise 1-18 mentioned in the C Answers Book, The exercise asks for the following: Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

I'm trying to test it on cygwin for windows as follows:

```
./ex1_18.exe <text.txt >t.txt
```

but the resulted file (t.txt) is a typical copy of the original file (text.txt) with the same trailing blanks and tabs.
what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

this is the C answers book's solution (with some changes to function names):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getln(char Line[], int maxline);
int remov(char s[]);

main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while(getln(line, MAXLINE)>0)
        if(remov(line)>0)
            printf("%s", line);
        return 0;

}

int remov(char s[])
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(s[i]!='\n')
        ++i;
    --i;
    while(i>=0 && (s[i]==' ' || s[i] == '\t'))
        --i;
    if(i>=0){
        ++i;
        s[i]='\n';
        ++i;
        s[i]='\0';

    }
    return i;
}

int getln(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i, j;
    j=0;
    for(i=0; (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n'; ++i)
        if(i< lim -2){
            s[j]=c;
            ++j;
        }
    if(c=='\n'){
        s[j]=c;
        ++j;
        ++i;
    }
    s[j]='\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is supposed to happen?  We don't all have a copy of that book.

Comment: It works when run from a windows console (no cygwin). Perhaps the problem is using `\n`, should you try `\r`?

Comment: I presume with cygwin you have to be careful not to try to read a windows text file... Is your file text.txt a UNIX text file?

Comment: Perhaps avoid the explicit testing and writing of `\n` and use functions `fgets` and `puts`.